# Buildroot group file ends up with odd entries

Tags: linux, buildroot

My goal is to understand why Buildroot is generating odd-looking output in my `group` file and determine if this will pose a problem. If it does pose a problem, I want to identify the cause and find a solution.

I am using Buildroot to create a Linux image and taking using `BR2_ROOTFS_USERS_TABLES` to create additional users in a table that looks like this:

```
#username  uid group gid password  home  shell groups  comment
cow 1022  four_legs 155 fake  /home/cow /bin/bash -
duck  1023  wings 156 fake  /home/duck  /bin/bash -
goose 1024  wings 156 fake  /home/goose /bin/bash -
pig 1025  four_legs 155 fake  /home/pig /bin/bash -
horse 1026  four_legs 155 fake  /home/horse /bin/bash -
chicken 1027  wings 156 fake  /home/chicken /bin/bash -
fish  1028  fins  157 fake  /home/fish  /bin/bash -
```

My fields are space-delimited, as directed by [the documentation](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#makeuser-syntax).

I end up with some oddities that I'd like to understand but don't. My `group` file looks like this:

```
/etc # cat group
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:root
cdrom:x:11:
dialout:x:18:
floppy:x:19:
video:x:28:
audio:x:29:
tape:x:32:
www-data:x:33:
operator:x:37:
utmp:x:43:
plugdev:x:46:
staff:x:50:
lock:x:54:
netdev:x:82:
users:x:100:
nobody:x:65534:four_legs:x:155:
four_legs:x:155:
wings:x:156:
fins:x:157:
sshd:x:1000:
:x:1001:cow,duck,goose,pig,horse,chicken,fish
```

1: On the line with `nobody`, it adds `four_legs` group without a line break, which it then repeats on the following line. I do not see why it's generating that way. **Will this cause issues to have `four_legs` on the same line as nobody and then have it repeated on the next line?**

2: On the last line, it creates what looks to be an unnamed group with a new GID and the members are all the users that I added from my table. **Do I need this last line? If so, what is it for?** Am I feeding something in wrong to make it give me a weird groups file?

A full clean build doesn't seem to change this and both `passwd` and `shadow` look as I would expect given this input. Also the order of the entries in the users table doesn't seem to have an effect. The first new group defined there gets repeated on the `nobody` line.

Last note: if I include a comment in the comment field, Buildroot gets messed up and dumps much of the above file into `passwd`.

Comment: This sure looks like a bug either in buildroot or in a data file that it reads.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this was my fault entirely, and was a combination of three things:

1. I had built my table of users in a spreadsheet and pasted the results into my text editor, and it looked fine enough, but, in Excel, fields that start with a few specific characters must be escaped via the single quote mark, `'`, which I used for fields that start with `=` or with `/`. When pasting, this introduced extra spaces, which turned out to be a problem. Easy enough to fix.
2. The `nobody:x:65534:four_legs:x:155:` issue goes away entirely if you simply make sure there is a newline at the end of the source file it will be appending to. Not sure why it repeated the entry instead of just leaving it on the `nobody` line, but okay, fine.
3. Make sure to have LF line endings instead of CRLF. It seems a lot more tolerant of my other issues now that if have LF line endings. And the Comment field works as it should too. :-)